# How do I count the number of contacts/emails in Office 365

Tags: office-365

I only have access to the web interface.

How do I count the number of contacts for a user? I have full admin access as well as access to the account in question.

- In Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> highlights the whole page. Holding <kbd>shift</kbd> and keying up/down doesn't work.
- In Internet Explorer, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> does nothing. Holding <kbd>shift</kbd> and keying up/down performs a nice scroll, but does not highlight anything.

I have looked at the People tab and done a search for the first two digits of the number of contacts. (Searched for 35 when the expected contacts are 3530)

Answer (score -1):

Install the Powershell module for the ***Office365*** or ***Windows Azure AD***.

After the installation you can find the so many cmdlet which is related to Office365.

For Example the cmdlet "Get-MsolUser" lists the complete user information in Office365.

check this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/feba32b0-b7eb-4b1b-ba3d-99e20ba82a8c) for more detail.

Also check this [link](http://ryanmangansitblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/connect-to-office-365-exchange-online-from-powershell/), if you have any problem to login Office365 using Powershell.